# Interactors VS Command

Tags: asp.net-web-api, architecture, asp.net-web-api2, command-pattern

I'm building a web api application. I was wondering what is the best way to call the use case layer.
One option is use uncle bob's interactors as it described here: [Interactors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpkDN78P884)
Another option is use command pattern as described here: [Command Pattern](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)

The main difference between the solutions at least from my understanding is that in the interactors solution the controller doesn't know the handler, it just sends a request and some interactor will do the job, while in the command option the controller needs to invoke the command.

What do you think is the better solution?

Comment: In the beginning of my projects, I prefer using Interactor since its more lightweight and easy to implement.

Comment: Without more context, this question is just asking for opinions.